# How to print the words using matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

I want to print `3` city names by using matrix in `C`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    char city[15];
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the city");
        scanf("%s",city[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
        printf("The city that was entered");
        printf("%s",city[i]);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code terminal took just one value. How can I print `3` city names?

Comment: You may start by declaring a multidimensional array: `char city[3][15];`, instead of a plain array of `char`.

Comment: The bare minimum changes needed in your code is - replace this `city[15]` with `city[3][15]` (provided none of the city name length is greater than `14` characters).

Comment: You need to study arrays then pointers, before using strings. In particular, `char` is not a string class. See this beginner FAQ: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is a single character, and `char city[15]` is an array of 15 characters.

To store 15 strings (one for each city name) it would need to be like `char city[15][101]`. This would allow 100 characters for each city name, plus the terminating 0 character. (Strings in C get a 0 char at the end).

Then `scanf("%s",city[i])` would work.

However if the user enters more than 100 characters for the city name, it would cause a buffer overflow. A way to prevent this is to use `scanf("%100s",city[i]);`.